# Overriding css appearance value with its default value

Tags: html, css

I have integrated `skel` CSS framework with `Bootstrap` on a web template due to some missing components in the template that was originally build on `skel` and I had no other choice..

Bottom line..

All `selectboxes` are set as

```
{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none
}
```

in order to remove the select arrow and apply custom styling.

I have a select that I want to view as default and am trying to override the `appearance` and set it back to normal.

I tried

```
{
  -webkit-appearance: default;
  appearance: default
}
```

and

```
{
  -webkit-appearance: initial;
  appearance: initial`
}
```

but it ain't working.

How can I set back the original appearance of the select?

Comment: Have you tried inlining it in it's style tag? Something like `<select style="appearance: window">`

Comment: Am using !important, so I think its the same

Comment: I don't think it's possible for the `appearance` property since it's a non-standard feature [(as stated by MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance). It doesn't have an initial value, which means that the value `initial` won't work. The default value is defined by the user agent stylesheet implementation.

Comment: @KAD how about the `appearance: window` part?

Comment: I think I shall narrow the selection of the original css that is setting it to none

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can do it if you use `appearance:menulist`

#### Snippet:

```css
.reset {
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  -moz-appearance:none;
  appearance:none;
}
.select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  -moz-appearance: menulist; 
  appearance: menulist; 
}
```

```html
<select class="reset select"></select>
```

See more about `appearence` and which values can it use [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/)