# Get back default appearence for select element

Tags: css

Here is the question similar to mine:
[Overriding css appearance value with its default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372457/overriding-css-appearance-value-with-its-default-value)

But in the case if select element has also background/border styles, overriding them to "none" or "initial" doesn't get expected results.

Example:

HTML

```
<body>
    <select class="select reset">
        <option value="1">Option Value 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option Value 2</option>
    </select>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.reset {
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}

.select {
    -webkit-appearance: menulist;
    -moz-appearance: menulist; 
    appearance: menulist;
    background: white;
    border: 2px solid #777;
}
```

THis is how select element looks without any styles:
[image]

Then after it gets ".select" class:
[image]

Styles within ".select" are coming from third-party library, so I cannot change them. But I need to reset how select element looks to its defaults in my project (look at the first picture).

This is what happens when I add ".reset" styles for that purpose:
[image]

No borders, no background. And no default appearance)

Comment: Please add also html and explain what is expected and what is happening that you don't want to happen?

Comment: Added more details

Comment: Do you have any way to override the existing CSS ?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

What you would like is [the `revert` keyword](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-cascade/#default) (and probably [the `all` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#all-shorthand)) to be implemented.

This is not the case yet so you'll have to remove your `select` class and avoid putting `reset` on native-looking `<select>` (this also makes more sense).

---

> Styles within ".select" are coming from third-party library, so I cannot change them. But I need to reset how select element looks to its defaults in my project (look at the first picture).

Seems your project shouldn't use user-agent styles as default then.

Comment: I cannot remove "select" class, because it goes with third-party library. What I need is to override those styles to default values in my project.

Comment: > Seems your project shouldn't use user-agent styles as default then.

Answer (score 0):

The order of class definitions in your CSS is very important, you need to put the overriding one after the one that you want to be overridden.

Example:

```css
.wrongreset {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  -moz-appearance: menulist;
  appearance: menulist;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #777;
}

.reset {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option>12</option><option>345</option>
</select>

<select class="select reset">
  <option>abc</option><option>de</option>
</select>

<select class="select wrongreset">
  <option>$%</option><option>#!@</option>
</select>
```

Another approach is to use a library such as jQuery to remove unwanted CSS classes, so the browser default styles (whatever they are) will apply again:

```js
$("#select1").removeClass("select");
```

```css
.select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  -moz-appearance: menulist;
  appearance: menulist;
  background: white;
  border: 2px solid #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select1" class="select">
  <option>12</option><option>345</option>
</select>
<select id="select2" class="select">
  <option>abc</option><option>de</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I added more details. Issue is not with styles order (but yes, in my example it may seems so)

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe the 2nd part can do what you need.

Comment: Second part works, but I won't use javascript for that. For me the question was about interesting behavior of css. And it seems that there is no solution) Anyway thanks